# Error while pkg building

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ros Melodic, Gazebo 9, Ubuntu 18.04.
I have downloaded a pkg from github as zip and extracted and pasted in the `home/usr/catkin_ws/src` and when I try to build the pkg by using `catkin build` , as i have used this command for my previous packages. but it through a lot of error can any one help me to resolve these. I'm attaching a screenshot of the terminal ![screenshot1.png] ![screenshot2.png]

### rethen@Rethen:~/catkin_ws$ catkin build

### Profile:                     default
Extending:          [cached] /opt/ros/melodic
Workspace:                   /home/rethen/catkin_ws

### Build Space:        [exists] /home/rethen/catkin_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/rethen/catkin_ws/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/rethen/catkin_ws/install
Log Space:          [exists] /home/rethen/catkin_ws/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /home/rethen/catkin_ws/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None

### Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None

### Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False

### Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None

### Workspace configuration appears valid.

[build] Found '11' packages in 0.0 seconds.
[build] Package table is up to date.
Starting  >>> ebot_controller
Starting  >>> ebot_description
Starting  >>> ebot_gazebo
Starting  >>> gazebo_ros_link_attacher
Starting  >>> maze_robotcraft
Starting  >>> pid_tune
Starting  >>> pkg_techfest_imc
Starting  >>> racing
Starting  >>> smart_mouse_sim
Starting  >>> stage_launch
Starting  >>> vitarana_drone

---

Errors     << smart_mouse_sim:cmake /home/rethen/catkin_ws/logs/smart_mouse_sim/build.cmake.002.log
CMake Error at /home/rethen/catkin_ws/src/smartmouse_simulator_master/src/core/test/CMakeLists.txt:14 (gtest_discover_tests):
Unknown CMake command "gtest_discover_tests".

cd /home/rethen/catkin_ws/build/smart_mouse_sim; catkin build --get-env smart_mouse_sim | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/rethen/catkin_ws/src/smartmouse_simulator_master --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/rethen/catkin_ws/devel/.private/smart_mouse_sim -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/rethen/catkin_ws/install; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << smart_mouse_sim:cmake                   [ Exited with code 1 ]
Failed    <<< smart_mouse_sim                         [ 0.2 seconds ]
Finished  <<< ebot_controller                         [ 0.2 seconds ]
Finished  <<< ebot_description                        [ 0.2 seconds ]
Finished  <<< pkg_techfest_imc                        [ 0.2 seconds ]
Finished  <<< gazebo_ros_link_attacher                [ 0.4 seconds ]
Finished  <<< pid_tune                                [ 0.4 seconds ]
Finished  <<< maze_robotcraft                         [ 0.4 seconds ]
Finished  <<< ebot_gazebo                             [ 0.2 seconds ]

---

Errors     << racing:cmake /home/rethen/catkin_ws/logs/racing/build.cmake.002.log
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "move_base_msgs"
with any of the following names:

```
move_base_msgsConfig.cmake
move_base_msgs-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "move_base_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"move_base_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"move_base_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

cd /home/rethen/catkin_ws/build/racing; catkin build --get-env racing | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/rethen/catkin_ws/src/MazeRunnerROS-master/racing --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/rethen/catkin_ws/devel/.private/racing -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/rethen/catkin_ws/install; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << racing:cmake                            [ Exited with code 1 ]
Failed    <<< racing                                  [ 1.0 seconds ]
Finished  <<< vitarana_drone                          [ 0.5 seconds ]
Finished  <<< stage_launch                            [ 0.2 seconds ]
[build] Summary: 9 of 11 packages succeeded.
[build]   Ignored:   None.
[build]   Warnings:  None.
[build]   Abandoned: None.
[build]   Failed:    2 packages failed.
[build] Runtime: 1.4 seconds total.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365599/error-while-pkg-building/) by [Rethen](https://answers.ros.org/users/63369/rethen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-11-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you missed to install move_base_msgs package

Make sure to install all the dependencies

You can install all the dependencies by running this instruction inside your workspace

> rosdep install --from-paths src
> --ignore-src -r -y

---

Originally posted by [Moneera Banjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/60255/moneera-banjar/) with karma: 108 on 2020-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1